# PHP Forms to Email - Input not sending to email

Tags: php, email, post

```
<?php

// Function that validates your formfields and generate errors
function validate($name, $email)
{
$errors = array();

// validation for name
if(strlen($name) < 2)
    $errors[] = 'You did not enter a name.';

// validation for email
if(!strlen($email))
    $errors[] = 'non-valid email.';
else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    $errors[] = 'valid email.';

// return array with errors
return $errors;
}

// initialization of variables with default values
$name = '';
$email = '';
$errors = array();

// if the form has been submited
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
// overwrite the variables with the $_POST elements
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

The Code I'm trying to add  (

```
$recipient = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Simple Forms';
$mailheader = 'From: $email \r\n';
$formcontent = '$name, $email';
```

)

```
// validate the variables
$errors = validate($name, $email);

// If there aren't any errors redirect to another page
if(!count($errors))
{
    // Here comes the place to send an email!!!
```

The code I'm trying to add (

```
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
```

)

```
    header('Location: contact.html');
    exit;
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>a titel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="errors">
    <?php
        foreach($errors as $error)
        echo '<li>' . $error . '</li>';
    ?>
    </ul>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The email is sending to the recipient correctly and with the correct subject line but it's from $email rn and the body of the email reads: $name, $email.

example email)

from: $email rn
to: example@gmail.com
Simple Forms

$name, $email

It's very close to working but I'm not sure how to use the $name and $email variable correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$formcontent = '$name, $email';` to `$formcontent = "$name, $email";` MAGIC!

Comment: [It is rather Strange Magic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11A8JZ-RDDo) - @Dagon

Comment: well its a [kind of magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0p_1QSUsbsM) @Fred-ii-